# How to programmatically add Active Directory groups to a Sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, active-directory, groups

Which is the proper way to add an Active Directory group to an SP group? I've tried with no luck. I'm using SCOM.

Thank you

```
 User user =  web1.EnsureUser("TheOwners");
 User user =  web1.EnsureUser(@"DOMAIN\TheOwners");
 web1.SiteGroups.GetByName(newGroupInfo.Title).Users.AddUser(user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as

```
SPGroup g = //Populate it

SPUser u = web1.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\\TheOwners");
g.AddUser(u);
```

Comment: Will it work even if the group is nested inside OUs? Also, I'm using SCOM

Comment: Yes It will work. The code i posted is also Sever Side Object Model.